# How to calculate retention curve in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Given eventLog table that has `userid` and `ds` columns. This represents all events that a given user made on a "website".

Sample data:

| userid | ds |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | 2022-01-01 |
| user2 | 2022-02-11 |
| user2 | 2022-03-21 |
| user3 | 2022-01-11 |
| user3 | 2022-02-27 |
| user3 | 2022-04-06 |

I need to calculate the monthly retention curve starting with the earliest month in the table. User considered as churned if they do not perform an action (don't have a record in `eventLog`) in a given month.

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ds, '%Y-%m-01') as ds_month
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT userid) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) as retention_rate
FROM eventLog
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(ds, '%Y-%m-01')
```

Here's fiddle: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6bdefc/4](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6bdefc/10)

I'm getting this output:

[image]

Expected outcome is:

| month | retention_rate | Reasoning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 100% | This is 100% by definition - user1 and user3 did the first action during this month |
| 2022-02-01 | 66% | 2 / 3 users retained (user2 did the first action, user3 retained, user1 churned) |
| 2022-03-01 | 33% | 1 / 3 users retained (user2 retained, user1 and user3 churned) |
| 2022-04-01 | 33% | 1 / 3 users retained (user3 retained, user1 and user2 churned) |

Comment: #1. Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. It must contain all possible variations. And desired output for this table as table-formatted text. #2. The user accesses in 01 and in 03 - does he must be counted in 03 as retained? #3. What is precise MySQL version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to divide your `COUNT(DISTINCT userid)` by the **total** distinct user count in the table; which a subquery can do: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) FROM eventLog`. Combine that with an `IF` statement to check if `2022-01-01` exists as a value to return `100%` (if I understood your logic correctly).

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(ds, '%Y-%m-01') as ds_month,
  CONCAT(FLOOR(IF(DATE_FORMAT(ds, '%Y-%m-01') = DATE_FORMAT(ds, '%Y-01-01'),100,(COUNT(DISTINCT userid)*100.0)/(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) FROM eventLog))),'%') AS user_count
FROM eventLog
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(ds, '%Y-%m-01')
```

**Result:**

```
| ds_month   | user_count  |
|------------|-------------|
| 2022-01-01 | 100%        |
| 2022-02-01 | 66%         |
| 2022-03-01 | 33%         |
| 2022-04-01 | 33%         |
```

**Note:** I used the `FLOOR()` function because you returned `66%` not `67%` for `2022-02-01`. You can use `FORMAT(column, 0)` (or whatever decimal place you desire) to round `2022-02-01` up properly to `67%` if needed.

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/hzBDXTVN).**